Fuzzy regression discontinuity: inconsistency between results from IV and RDROBUST
I'm using a Fuzzy Regression Discontinuity to estimate the effect of retirement on time spent on household chores. My outcome variable is the minutes spent on "Unpaid work", my treatment variable is retirement (as defined by the individual), and my instrument is pension eligibility (Z=1 if x≥0, 0 otherwise). The variable x represents my running variable (when the individual is older than the retirement age, it takes positive values; if the individual has not reached the retirement age yet, it takes negative values).
I would expect workers to have x<0 and all retirees to have x>0; however, some eligible individuals for retirement continue to work and other individuals who are not yet eligible are already retired (due to reasons such as disability, illness, and other factors beyond my control).
When in Stata I use the rdrobust command
rdrobust unpaid_work x, fuzzy(retirement) kernel(uniform) bwselect(mserd) p(1) all)

I get different results compared to when I use IV
rdbwselect unpaid_work x, fuzzy(retirement) bwselect(mserd) kernel(uniform) 
global left =-e(h_mserd) 
global right=e(h_mserd) 
ivreg unpaid_work x (retirement=z) if x>$left &x<$right , robust first


This happens even if I use covariates, interaction terms, or different polynomial degrees. How is this possible?
With rdrobust I get positive and significant results both for the first stage and for my outcome variable of interest. With a IV I get insignificant and with opposite sign estimates for the first stage and I cannot consider the estimate for the y.

I think you'd be much better off asking this on Statalist. Questions about what results mean and why you get results that are puzzling don't add up to a precise Stata programming problem.
